# e.Query as IQueryable<CombinedAppointment> always returns null

Tags: c#, iqueryable

When I try to assign a value to variable like I show below it is always `null`, why is this?

```cs
var query = e.Query as IQueryable<CombinedAppointment>;
```

Comment: Does `e.Query` is not null? What is `e.Query` type? Try run `e.Query.GetType()` from Immediate Window in Visual Studio

Comment: Well, isn't it obvious? `query` can only be null by that statement if `e.Query` isn't of the type you are specifing. It's basically this `var apple = banana as Apple;` well `banana` isn't an `Apple` so `apple` will be null.

Comment: @randomrandom so how can i achieve my goal, say i want to assign a var as a banana as an apple?

Comment: @KarimTingdis correct answer depends on `e.Query` type. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54887413/edit) your question and add this information